# BMW 520D M Sport 2008 - Loses power then fails to start shortly after

Tags: bmw, diesel, power-loss, diesel-particulate-filter

First had this issue 6 months ago, Engine slowly stalled then when attempting to restart it died out after 10-15 seconds of running with some smoke coming from the front of the engine.

Diagnosis was showing DPF filter so cleaned out DPF and inlet manifold only to still have the same issue.

Diagnosed again seemed to display an issue with the fuel supply so switched the fuel rail and changed the battery car was then running fine and actually passed the new style MOT! Up until last week following a service inc oils/filter changes. Car seemed to lose power during driving and eventually stall and when attempting to restart it died out after 10-15 seconds of running.

Engine would continue to cut out after starting the ignition. Diagnosed again when it began to run for a while and attempted to drive a short distance. There seemed a slight difference within the airflow levels to and from the turbo so considering sending turbo to a specialist but thought I would reach out first to see if anyone has had a similar issue before?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks @Paulster2 ! Know anyone that could help with this issue?

Comment: Update - have since blocked off the EGR and car is able to start and run without cutting out. However, smoke is still visible when revving on standstill..

Have previously cleaned the EGR but half bought a sourced a new one to see if it resolves the problem

If anyone else has had a similar issue please get in touch, will update with findings after changing EGR this week!

Comment: Is the smoke black or blue?

Comment: Blue as its grey seems to be coming from the back of the engine and even thought the car is running with EGR blocked off it still feels clunky when applying the throttle... changing EGR tonight so will see how it drives then and if the smoke clears?

Comment: Replaced EGR seems to running smoother and not as clunky when applying throttle. Was still seeing blue smoke but a longish drive seemed to be the cure so maybe there is still a lot of excess oil in and around the Inlet Manifold?

Comment: A properly working EGR is not going to hurt anything, that's for sure. As far as the blue smoke, it would indicate excess oil coming from some place. On a diesel, that usually doesn't cure itself. Keep an eye on it, as well as your oil levels.

Comment: So looked to be running much smoother until on the motorway, seemed to be limited to 70mph and eventually lost power/acceleration?

Comment: Took it to a local garage for another opinion and feedback recommendation is to switch the Inlet Manifold as the plastic flaps inside are intermittent when in use and that is effecting the airflow?

Comment: So held off taken it to the garage and took off the Inlet Manifold following some very detailed and useful youtube videos... Unit was completely full of carbon style clay!

Have cleaned all the carbon out and repaird a bearing which had unclipped as there seems no physical problem with the swirl flaps will leave them on and see how it goes once all back together....

Comment: All back together with EGR still blocked off ran fine after a motorway test run, took EGR blank off this morning to check without that and engine cut out after 30 seconds again? Bearing in mind this is a brand new EGR?

Comment: Put the EGR blank back on and see if the engine runs just fine again. Leave it in place for some time (a few days) too see if the EGR is actually the issue. I'm wondering if you have a secondary issue which seems to be floating around the EGR, but isn't it.

Comment: Have been driving short distances for a while with no problem yet to take the risk of going on a long motorway journey which will be the ultimate test... this is all with the blank back on as again not starting with it removed!

Comment: So was working fine for a short while then we noticed a strong smell of smoke within the car and a hissing sound from under the bonnet looks to be whole somewhere or a leak at least between the CAT and the DPF at the front of the engine?

Comment: Taken DPF off to find it is blocked at the front with a sooty mixture, hopefully this is what caused the back pressure and hoping since we have cleaned the inlet manifold out this should reduce the amount of crap getting through!? 

I was feeling brave and decided to remove the EGR Blank! It was very clunky to start but seems to be improving and no signs of it cutting out as of yet but this was only for a short few miles of a test drive